# what CSS could cause a page margin to break on bottom / right sides?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an HTML page with the following CSS:

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 5rem;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

When I inspect the `body` element in Chrome, I can only "see" the margin being applied on the left and top. The bottom and right sides seem to be forcing off the page/layout. This is causing some of my inner content (inside body) to be half cut off as it's "off" the screen.

additionally, No scroll bars are appearing anywhere in the layout, despite adding `overflow: scroll`, I am not able to scroll to the "hidden" content.

Of course there are more elements inside of body, but the layout is too large/complex to reproduce here. What are some things to look for that could be cause the layout to overflow on the right and bottom?

Basically I am unsure as to why the margin is only visible on the top and left, and what kind of CSS I should look for that could be causing this.

EDIT:: Additionally, if I change `body` to have `margin: 2rem auto`, the margin is only visible on the "top", not left/bottom/right.

Comment: Can we see an example? or fiddle?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to mock up a fiddle at the moment, the page is fairly heavy/complex so I'm not sure if I can get an accurate recreation :/ mostly just looking for tips in what to look for when debugging common layout bugs

Comment: Check my fiddle, I think that is what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my answer (completely failed that one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html` has `position: fixed` and is the same width and height of the browser.  Therefore, when you use margins on the `body` the top and left margins just push it's content down and right out of `html`.  This is why you can't see its bottom and right margins.

**Example**

```css
*,*::before,*::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
.html {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 5rem;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.body::before,
.body::after {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 5px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.body::before {
    content: "body top-margin";
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    bottom: 100%;
    border-top: none;
}

.body::after {
    content: "body left-margin";
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100%;
    right: 100%;
    border-left: none;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="html"><p>html</p>
<div class="body"><p>body</p></div></div>
```

Comment: If I replace margin with padding, it still occurs. Basically I'm just trying to have a 5rem buffer around the window -- would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: If you use `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding` on `body` then it should work.

Comment: This did the trick. I thought my CSS reset had set everything to `border-box` but apparently not! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is 100% width with margin.  Setting 100% on the body sets it to 100% of the window width and so applying margin to that pushes the body off of the right side.  In this case your body is 100% of the window width + 10rem.  You could do something like `body{width: 90vw; margin: 5vw;}` I like that solution because then the margins scale with client size, plus using vw makes it clearer that the body width percentage is in relation to the client.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can try to use this css (no width or height here):

```
body {
        top: 5rem;
        right: 5rem;
        bottom: 5rem;
        left: 5rem;
        position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to make windowed/framed appearance for your page. Take a look at this snippet. You will want to set `box-sizing:border-box` to your `body` element and change the margin to padding. Then you will want to use an element such as a `div` as your content container. Set that container to `height:100%` and `overflow:scroll;`.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 5rem;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div {
    background: teal none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br /></div>
  </body>
</html>
```